# Facebook Login Firebase

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on an app that utilizes Firebase for its backend. A user needs to login via Facebook. This is working fine; after a successful Facebook login, a user gets created in Firebase.

The thing that is not clear to me is what happens after the Facebook token expires. I obviously need to re-enter my Facebook credentials, but how does Firebase know which user is connected to that same Facebook account, but with a new access token?

Hopefully you can clear this up for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user signs in to an app with their Facebook login, they get a unique ID for that app from Facebook. If the user ever signs in to the same app with Facebook again, they get that same ID.